# How to define F<T> and F<T,U> and F<T,U,V> interfaces in Java?

Tags: java

How would I define `F<T>` and `F<T,U>` and `F<T,U,V>` interfaces in Java (in lieu of `Action` from C#, they would have functions with one, two and three parameters returning void inside)?

When I try to create them as nested types, I get an error saying "Duplicate nested type F",  when I try to create them as top-level types, I would have to place both `F<T>` and `F<T,U>` in F.java.

I might be able to solve this by placing each F in separate package, but I don't like that solution as I'd have to define as many packages as many generic parameters I would have.

The same would go for implementing a Tuple class with multiple generic parameters, etc.

code sample, not working:

```
public interface F<T>{
    public void f(T arg1);
}

public interface F<T,U>{
    public void f(T arg1,U arg2);
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example of the code that gives an error? I'm finding it difficult to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Don't you want to define the generic types at the method level instead?

Comment: @assylias - no, as I'd like to pass use this as a "function pointer" for callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with the same interface name. Java erases the parameterized types.

Other toolkits have done something similar using names like F1<T>, F2<T1, T2> and F3<T1, T2, T3>. It's a little more verbose, but works.

Answer (score 1):

> I would have to place both F and F in F.java.

Because `F` is defined as `public` (this can be ommited)

Also avoid multiple interfaces with the same name. There is never a good reason to do that!

```
interface F<T,U,V>{
   public void f(T arg1);
   public void f(T arg1, U arg2, V arg3);
   public void f(T arg1, U arg2);
}

public class TryTest<T,U,V> implements F<T,U,V>{
   public void f(T arg1, U arg2){ }
   public void f(T arg1) { }
   public void f(T arg1, U arg2, V arg3) { }
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      System.out.println("Works!");
   }
}
```

Comment: it would work, but whenever I'd like to use this interface, I would have to implement all of these methods. Implementing an interface to pass around some action is already too much hassle compared to C# lambda methods, but having to implement 3 or more methods each time would be too much :(

Comment: If you use an IDE, the IDE inserts them for you automatically when you declare `implements` :-) . Java just does not allow default parameterization of generics like C# does. C# is a much more advanced language.

Comment: I am aware of that and greatly appreciate Eclipse for doing that, I just hate that something that will take 1 line in C# takes 5 in Java for this. But it's something we have to live for, until Java introduces lambdas, if ever.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't have two interfaces with the same name. Generics (raw types) are not used during compile time, and therefore compiler wouldn't differentiate them.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, a generic type has a fixed number of type paramters. Therefore, if you need different number of parameters, you need different types:

```
interface F1<T> {
    void f(T arg);
}

interface F2<T, U> {
    void f(T t, U u);
}
```

and so on.